# Does a purely tangential force create centripetal force?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force

Suppose there's a circular disc pivoted at is center and a purely tangential force is applied to change the angular speed of the disc. So as the disc's rotation speed changes constantly, the particles get accelerated towards the center too. Has the tangential force created centripetal force or something ?

Comment: If the disc is rotating, then there is a centripetal force. The attractive forces between each particle of the disc provide centripetal force for each of them.

Comment: Is the production of radial force an automatic consequence of rotation about the axis ?

Comment: Because there was no centripetal force before, when the disc was at rest.

Comment: Just from the fact that the body is rigid, there is a constraint that all particle must move together (in a sense of the word). Intermolecular forces provide acceleration to all particles in such a way that the constraint is true.

Comment: Huh..strange thing..Nature works in weird ways. Thanks guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangential force somewhat creates the centripetal force.

The centripetal force is a reaction of the object or system to the tangential force.  In the case of a disk, when you apply the tangential force somewhere, if the disk is being held so it can only rotate, then the tangential motion won't be able to accelerate the disk in the direction of force.

Instead, the internal forces holding the disk together create an acceleration inwards so that the place where you apply the force doesn't just break off.  Since it can only rotate the tangential force induces the centripetal force.

It's easy to picture with a ball on a string spinning around.  The ball wants to move forward but because of the length of the string being fixed, the tension of the string makes a centripetal acceleration.